# Comprobar si en una cadena se encuentra otra

Tags: c++, funciones, condiciones, entrada

Resulta que tengo que elaborar un programa que mediante una función de tipo `bool` y `find()` hacer que devuelva un mensaje si `s1` se encuentra en `s2`.

Me falla el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Failed example:
    printf 'hello how are you\nbye' | ./program
Expected:
    No, it does not exist
Got:
    Yes, it exists
```

Adjunto el programa :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool substringExists(string s, string subs){
    if (s.find(subs)){
      return true;
    }else{
     return false;
    }
                                           }
int main(){
    string s1, s2;
  cin >> s1 >> s2;
  if (substringExists(s1,s2)){
    cout << "Yes, it exists";
                           }
  else{
    cout << "No, it does not exist";
      } 
  return 0;
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te está fallando porque la función **`find`**, en caso de no encontrar **`subs`** dentro de s te estará devolviendo **`string::npos (-1)`**

Prueba así:

```
bool substringExists(string s, string subs){
    retun (s.find(subs) != string::npos);
}
```

Comment: Que hace exactamente string::npos ?

Comment: Me da otro error Failed example:
    printf 'hello how are you\nhow' | ./program
Expected:
    Yes, it exists
Got:
    No, it does not exist